# Why is strncpy marked as unsafe?

Tags: c++

I am getting a warning:

```
warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using  strncpy_s instead.
To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
F:\vuStudio\VC\include\string.h(188) : see declaration of 'strncpy'
```

I read on stackoverflow.com that `strcpy` is not safe and I should use `strncpy` instead. But now why I am getting warning that strncpy is unsafe ?

I am calling it as:

```
strncpy(this->title, title.c_str(), sizeof(this->title));
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038614/how-to-achieve-strncpy-functionality-with-strncpy-s-function. It's not exactly a duplicate, but the information there answers your question. In short, you need to ensure that the destination string is nul terminated if you use `strncpy`; `strncpy_s` does this for you.

Comment: your example is not safe on its own: if `title.c_str()` is longer than `sizeof(this->title)` the `this->title` array will not be null terminated, and cause random crashes if you try to use it later. Use `strncpy(this->title, title.c_str(), sizeof(this->title)-1); this->title[sizeof(this->title)-1] = '\0';` to fix it

Comment: Did you want to tag this question C instead?

Comment: @pqnet: According to the C11 spec, you don't have to do the second line:
this->title[sizeof(this->title)-1] = '\0';
That is redundant as it is taken care, i.e., if a '\0' was not copied as part of strncpy_s then the dest[4TH_ARGUMENT_SIZE] will be filled with '\0'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strncpy` has a few dangerous quirks.

First, it zeros the target buffer past the end of the copy, which can be surprising.

Second, if there is not enough room in the target buffer, it does **not** null terminate the target buffer.

Third, if it truncates, it 'mostly works'.  Which discourages error handling (truncated strings are often worse than useless, but do not **appear** to be worse than useless at first glance).

`strncpy_s` requires an input length (or explicit truncation request), and errors if there is not enough room to null terminate (writing just a zero length string in the output).  The input length is sometimes inefficient to provide (and not required for some of its changes), but it does guarantee a null terminated output buffer (so long as it isn't a nullptr, or zero length) even in error conditions.  I am unsure if it zeros past the end of the copied string or not.

This behavior prevents or mitigates some common fenceposting errors in string code.

Answer (score 4):

Visual studio compiler has it's own implementation of `strncpy`, you won't get this warning with gcc or clang. It is safe, and more portable (because `strncpy_s` is not standard) to use `strncpy`.

If you don't care about portability, `strncpy_s` is indeed more secure because it has an additional length check (but like `strncpy` it won't save you if you pass bad parameter).

Answer (score -1):

The "n" variants of str functions (like strncmp, strncpy, etc) are the "safe" choice, because they all are limiting the size of string buffer used. 
The "old" str functions (not the "n" variants, like strcpy) are all subject to many programming errors and memory attacks (off by one, heap overwriting, etc).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: IMHO the answer to the question is already in the gcc warning. This is an explanation about "why" gcc is saying "see declaration of 'strncpy'".