# Why the code below excutes unexpected letters in the end of the string?

Tags: c, string

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int countNumber(char string[],int number_[]);
int countNumber(char string[]);


int main(){
  char string[] = "tran_huynh_minh_phuc";
  int num = countNumber(string)+1;
  int *number = (int *) calloc(num, sizeof(int));
  countNumber(string,number);
  for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
    printf("%d\n",number[i]);
  }

  fflush(stdin);
  char a[3][14];

  strncpy(a[2], string+5, 5);
  printf("%s",a[2]);


} 

int countNumber(char string[],int *number)
{   int count=0; 
    int num_i=1;
    number[0]=-1;
         for(int i=0; i<strlen(string); i++)
          {
           if(string[i]=='_')
             { number[num_i] = i;
               num_i++; 
             }  
          }
    return count;
}

int countNumber(char string[])
{   int count=0; 
         for(int i=0; i<strlen(string); i++)
          {
           if(string[i]=='_')
             { 
               count++; 
             }  
          }
    return count;
}
```

this is my problem console results:

[image]

I am doing the program to get the substring which will get "tran","huynh","minh" from "tran_huynh_minh", however it is appearing some unexpected letters at the end of my substring. In addition, I tried many ways to fix it but it did not work. Can you find my mistakes?

Thanks

Minh Phuc

Comment: Um, this isn't valid C and won't compile. Are you actually using (really bad) C++?

Comment: This can't possibly compile as C. `countNumber` is used *twice* as a function id, with different signatures to add salt to the wound.

Comment: Anyways, your use of `strncpy()` is probably to blame. People never read the fine print about how it works and assume it does something it actually doesn't (Always 0-terminate a string). Its use should be avoided.

Comment: @Shawn - A thousand times yes.  It sometimes null-terminates a string, and sometimes doesn't, and that's its *defined* behavior?  No thank you.

Comment: @Shawn or, like most things, people that don't *really* understand how it works shouldn't use it, or should learn how it *really* works before doing so. Ex: you'd be *amazed* how many people don't know that `strncpy` *always* writes `n` characters (where `n` is the specified length argument).  Life would be much better if people bothered to read docs rather than assume behavior just from a name.

Comment: Phúc Trần Huỳnh Minh, why does code has a final 5 in `strncpy(a[2], string+5, 5);` rather than 14?

Answer (score 0):

I think the intent for the bottom of the main block is something like this (this adds the null after the 'huynh' which was copied. By adding the null, when it goes to print a[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038614/how-to-achieve-strncpy-functionality-with-strncpy-s-function), it knows when to stop. It looks like the desire was to put the second word in the array at index 2 (presumably being done in a loop once it was working or the like):

```
strncpy(a[2], string + 5, 5);
a[2][5] = '\0';
printf("%s", a[2]);
```

If you run something equivalent to this, you should see the expected output. However, you likely also see a warning on the strncpy function and considering using strncpy_s (depending what you are using to compile. It looks like you are on windows). If you replace the function call with strncpy_s (assuming Visual Studio), you will get the desired result without adding the null at the end separately. Note it expects a size of the destination array as a safeguard (14 in this case).

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746400/why-is-strncpy-marked-as-unsafe) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038614/how-to-achieve-strncpy-functionality-with-strncpy-s-function).